# add params to url when user click to refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

On loading, my web page has the following url :

http://mywebsite.com?param1=test&param2=test2

I use the following code during startup to remove from url the parameters once the web page is loaded:

```
if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
}
```

Thus, my url becomes :

http://mywebsite.com

The problem is that the user refresh the page in the browser, i need to add again the parameters previously removed. How can i do that when the user refresh the page ?

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    // Add again parameters before reloading ..
});
```

Comment: Why remove them in the first place?  If you need the parameters to be there, leave them there.

Comment: you could use **localStorage** before clear them

Comment: This sounds like a pointless problem - if you need the parameters to be in the URL, leave them in the URL

Comment: @David Because my customer doesn't want to display the params..

Comment: Why do you need to remove the parameters in the first place?

Comment: This seems to be drastically overcomplicating things to satisfy a fairly arbitrary requirement.  Why are the parameters needed in the first place?  Is there some way other than the query string to accomplish that need?  Digging this whole deeper sounds like it's going to require more and more effort and cause a variety of edge cases (users who don't have JavaScript enabled, users who copy/paste a link manually, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the paramaters in localStorage and then check for their presence when the page is reloaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: The issue with this is how do you then get the page with the parameter-less state? The visitor would never be able to visit the `http://mywebsite.com` URL again

Comment: Then he could set/unset a flag variable to catch the refresh? like with window.onbeforeunload

Comment: You've got the querystring values in the user's localStorage, so when the user goes to www.mywebsite.com, just check for the presence of the parameters and then take whatever action you need to based on the parameters. If they go to www.mywebsite.com?param1=test&param2=test2, set the paramerers in localStorage and redirect to www.mywebsite.com. When the redirect happens, it will see that the parameters have been set and then you can take action.